# Route planner for given polygon

Tags: qgis

is there a way to generate route inside given polygon and starting point with azimuth. End result should be similar to something like picture below.
If such solution doesn't exists, what would be approach to make it?

[image]

Comment: How is this "route" defined? From "Home", then traversing the polygon via E-W lines at a given spacing, then back to Home? Do you want the shortest route? How complex can the polygon be?

Comment: Polygon can be any 4 vertex one with "reasonable" angles. At the beggining given point of entry is given and azimuth of starting route, the s-shape pattern is created with parallel lines until full space is exausted  exit point doesn't matter.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Thank you for welcome! I would gladly post the code or even put whole solution to github as open source but from my question it is very transparent that I am looking for whatever piece info I can find.